# Stored Procedures and Functions not working properly or found in Spring Data JPA and PostgreSQL 16

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, data-jpa-test

I am learning Spring Data JPA as part of my Spring Boot revision.
I am trying to use Stored procedures on the database, and i want to call them from my Spring Data JPA repositories.

I am trying to use the @Procedure annotation as well as native queries, I tried every possible combination and tried to be as detailed as possible,

I can't help but thin either I am missing something right in front of me, or there is a bug

I have checked the data types and everything matches as well as I can see.

```
-- The Postgresql stored procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE misc.createmisc(
    IN _name VARCHAR, 
    IN _mkey VARCHAR,
    IN _mvalue integer,
    OUT newid integer
)
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    INSERT INTO misc.misc (name, mkey, mvalue) VALUES (_name, _mkey, _mvalue) RETURNING id;
$$
```

If i call the procedure from the database client it works perfect:

```
-- Calling the procedure, both named & positional params work:
-- Positional params:
CALL createmisc('Name 2', 'mk2', 5, NULL);
-- Named params:
CALL createmisc(_name => 'Name 2', _mkey => 'mk3', _mvalue => 5, newId => NULL);
```

```
// The code in Spring Boot:
@Entity
/**
 * Need to create custom Getters and Setters for mKey and mValue
 * because the first char lower, then second caps, is causing issues with lombok,
 * but it works with intelliJ
 */
public class Misc {

    /**
     * Here this is a simple project, and only 1 misc will be inserted at a time,
     * For this, the IDENTITY generation type is okay
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String mKey;
    private Integer mValue;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setmKey(String mKey) {
        this.mKey = mKey;
    }

    public String getmKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    public Integer getmValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    /**
     * Just a normal method to try and show these as rich models,
     * If I have a rich model, It can do specific tasks,
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String expressMisc() {
        return "Misc: " + name + " is amazing ";
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * Learning how to call Stored Procedures from Spring Data JPA to PostgreSQL database
 */
public interface MiscStoredProcedureCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Misc, Integer> {

    /**
     * This works when return type is void
     * @param name
     * @param mkey
     * @param mvalue
     */
    @Procedure(procedureName = "createmisc", outputParameterName = "newid")
    public void callCreateMiscWithVoidReturn(String name, String mkey, Integer mvalue);

    /**
     * Here I am not mentioning anything to do with OUT parameter,
     * PostgreSQL expects an OUT parameter, but when there is a return type it fails,
     * Even though I choose the most generic object:
     * @param name
     * @param mkey
     * @param mvalue
     * @return
     */
    @Procedure(procedureName = "createmisc")
    public Object callStoredProcBaldenbugStyle(String name, String mkey, Integer mvalue);



    /**
     * Here I am going to try using the native query,
     * The arguments match completely fine but for some reason it can't find the procedure
     */
    @Query(
            value = "CALL misc.createmisc(:name, :mkey, :mvalue, :newid)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    public Integer callCreateMiscWithNativeQuery(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("mkey") String mkey,
            @Param("mvalue") Integer mvalue,
            @Param("newid") Integer newid
    );

    /**
     * Native query without Out parameter
     */
    @Query(
            value = "CALL createmisc(:name, :mkey, :mvalue, NULL)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    public Integer callCreateMiscWithNativeQueryNoOutParameter(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("mkey") String mkey,
            @Param("mvalue") Integer mvalue
    );

    /**
     * Calling native query without OUT parameter and No nulls
     */
    @Query(
            value = "CALL createmisc(:name, :mkey, :mvalue)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    public Integer callCreateMiscWithNativeQueryNoOutParameterNoNull(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("mkey") String mkey,
            @Param("mvalue") Integer mvalue
    );

}
```

I have followed this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures
I also tried every possible combination, It keeps saying procedure not found, might need explicit casts

Here is the tests for each of the functions with the trace:

```
@Test
// Passes:
    void callCreateMiscWithVoidReturn() {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        misc.setName("Misc from SP");
        misc.setmKey("mkj");
        misc.setMValue(110);

         miscStoredProcedureCrudRepository.callCreateMiscWithVoidReturn(
                misc.getName(), misc.getmKey(), misc.getmValue()
        );
    }


@Test
    void callStoredProcBaldenbugStyle() {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        misc.setName("Misc from SP");
        misc.setmKey("mkj");
        misc.setMValue(110);

        Object returningInt = miscStoredProcedureCrudRepository.callStoredProcBaldenbugStyle(
                misc.getName(), misc.getmKey(), misc.getmValue()
        );
    }

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: procedure createmisc(character varying, character varying, integer, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 6


@Test
    void callCreateMiscWithNativeQuery() {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        misc.setName("Misc from SP");
        misc.setmKey("mkj");
        misc.setMValue(110);

        miscStoredProcedureCrudRepository.callCreateMiscWithNativeQuery(
                misc.getName(), misc.getmKey(), misc.getmValue(), null
        );
    }

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: procedure misc.createmisc(character varying, character varying, integer, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 6

@Test
    void callCreateMiscWithNativeQueryNoOutParameter() {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        misc.setName("Misc from SP");
        misc.setmKey("mkj");
        misc.setMValue(110);

        miscStoredProcedureCrudRepository.callCreateMiscWithNativeQueryNoOutParameter(
                misc.getName(), misc.getmKey(), misc.getmValue()
        );

    }


Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: procedure createmisc(character varying, character varying, integer, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 6

@Test
    void callCreateMiscWithNativeQueryNoOutParameterNoNull() {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        misc.setName("Misc from SP");
        misc.setmKey("mkj");
        misc.setMValue(110);
        miscStoredProcedureCrudRepository.callCreateMiscWithNativeQueryNoOutParameterNoNull(
                misc.getName(), misc.getmKey(), misc.getmValue()
        );
    }


org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: JDBC exception executing SQL [CALL createmisc(?, ?, ?)] [No results were returned by the query.] [n/a]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at app//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:135)
    at app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:246)
```

I have tried every combination imaginable, but I can't seem to find a way,
Same thing is happenning with functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION misc.createmiscasfunc(_name character varying, _mkey character varying, _mvalue integer)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $$

INSERT INTO misc (name, mkey, mvalue) VALUES (_name, _mkey, _mvalue) RETURNING id;

$$

SELECT createmiscasfunc(
    _name => 'Named Param',
    _mkey => 'ddd2',
    _mvalue => 100
);
```

Creating a named native query:

```
/**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param mkey
     * @param mvalue
     * @return
     */
    @Query(
            value = "SELECT misc.createmiscasfunc(_name => :name, _mkey => :mkey, _mvalue => :mvalue) ",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    public Integer createMiscAsFunc(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("mkey") String mkey,
            @Param("mvalue") Integer mvalue
    );

@Test
    void createMiscAsFunc() {
        Misc misc = new Misc();
        misc.setName("Misc from SP");
        misc.setmKey("mkj");
        misc.setMValue(110);
        miscStoredProcedureCrudRepository.createMiscAsFunc(
                misc.getName(), misc.getmKey(), misc.getmValue()
        );
    }

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function misc.createmiscasfunc(_name => character varying, _mkey => character varying, _mvalue => integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 8
```

Comment: Just a guess: Try defining the params as `text` instead of `varchar`. Also, I've always used `returning` rather than `out` - try that too

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried both, made no difference, I removed the OUT parameter, but it still has that extra parameter when I have a return type as an object. I can't see why something like this should create issues, this is why I dont like working with these huge behemoth frameworks, its just too heavy and there is just too much going on

Comment: When I took away the OUT parameter and changed the return type to void in the return type, when I once again added a return type of Object, i get the same weird exception where It throws exceptions

Comment: @Bohemian, a `PROCEDURE` does not `RETURN` anything per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html: *https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html.  However, procedures can instead return data to their callers via output parameters.*

Comment: Yes, I would eventually like to return a record type from stored procedures, but this is just not working properly, I am getting strange results

Comment: That is because you can only use `OUT` to return data. If you want to use `RETURNS` you will need to do `CREATE FUNCTION`

Comment: Sure, but right now, I am just trying to return a simple integer value, its not even doing that, Is it not so that we can return a single record or row type with OUT ?

Comment: `newid` is an `OUT` parameter that needs to start as `NULL`, which is what you do in `psql` I presume. Is it `NULL` here `@Param("newid") Integer newid`?

Comment: Hey yes, when I can calling it from the test, I am passing null from Java

Comment: When i take away the 4th out parameter, i get this: No results were returned by the query. interesting, how could i pass that as null ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a stored procedure? This would be easy and natural with a function, not a procedure.

Comment: The reason for me to do Stored procedures is I like to manage all DML transactions at the database level as opposed to the server side application, There I can implement all kinds of complex management which would be a pain in Spring Boot, Also all the Stored procedures are compiled on the database, run blazing fast as opposed to sending 10 raw queries from the App to the DB, and then not having the kind of resultset I want, I am thinking of just learning JDBI after this, so I can just do this for simple projects

Comment: Fair enough, I am fully with you. Yet you can use both stored functions and stored procedures alike to achieve your goal. In this particular case a stored function will suit the case better. I have illustrated this in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a stored [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) instead of a [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html):

```sql
create or replace function misc.createmisc(_name text, _mkey text, _mvalue integer)
returns integer language sql volatile as
$$
 insert into misc.misc (name, mkey, mvalue) values (_name, _mkey, _mvalue)
 returning id;
$$;
```

Then the wrapper in Java:

```java
@Query(
  value = "select misc.createmisc(:name, :mkey, :mvalue)",
  nativeQuery = true
)
public Integer createMiscWithNativeQuery(
  @Param("name") String name,
  @Param("mkey") String mkey,
  @Param("mvalue") Integer mvalue
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am sorry I was an idiot and did not configure my environment properly with all the scripts, It was my fault, I could close this, but I am going to provide an answer as it might help others